# How to calculate velocity for a set distance and target velocity

Tags: javascript, math, physics, linear-algebra

I have a sprite animation where I have set a stopping distance to it and want to calculate how much i have to slow the object down in that stopping distance to reach its new target speed. But at the moment I am not getting the correct result.

My code looks like this:

```
function updatePosition(obj,brake){
    var delta  = new Date().getTime() - obj.timer; //time since last frame

    if(brake){          
        obj.velocity -= (Math.pow(obj.velocity,2) - Math.pow(obj.targetSpeed,2)) / (2 * obj.stopDist); 
        if(obj.velocity < obj.targetSpeed){
            obj.velocity = obj.targetSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the sprite goes far  past the stopping distance with a velocity well above the target speed.

I created a fiddle with a red dot travelling to a destination here: **http://jsfiddle.net/4tLmz3ch/1/**

When it travels the distance set by `obj.stopDist` it should be going the target speed which should be well before it reaches its destination. But i am obviously getting something incorrect with the math here.

Hope you can help explain my misunderstanding.

Comment: Velocity isn't a scalar value. You're mixing up scalar and vector calculations and I think that's one of the big problems here.

Comment: @JLRishe not 100% sure i understand what you mean? Should i not be changing the velocity value?

Comment: @Dave Velocity is a vector. It has a magnitude and a direction. In two dimensions, that alternatively means that it has an X component and a Y component. It's not just a single number.

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but it will be interesting to you if you are interested in physics programming in JS: http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html

Comment: @JLRishel i don't quite understand why it would hold anything but a pixels/per second value in my code. As i set its x:y position afterwards with delta.

Comment: @AdilAliyev thanks for link though i prefer to right code from scratch :)

Comment: @Dave You can get by the way you have it because the code assumes the dot is traveling at a 45-degree angle. (i.e. that Vx = Vy = `velocity`) At any other angle, though, you would need an actual vector for the velocity.

Comment: @JLRishe set any starting point and destination point and it travels in the correct direction for me: http://jsfiddle.net/n61e8pu5/

Comment: @Dave You've managed to get the dot to move in the right direction. That doesn't mean that the calculations are necessarily correct. If you want to do 2d physics, you should be using vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is a lot simpler if you determine the desired acceleration ahead of time, and use that during each refresh. Then the entire code for each frame (excluding the drawing logic and assuming one dimension) just becomes:

```
function frame() {
    var t = new Date().getTime();
    var tDelta = t - obj.lastTime;

    obj.lastTime = t;

    obj.pos += obj.velocity * tDelta;

    if (obj.velocity > obj.destVelocity) {
        obj.velocity += obj.acceleration * tDelta;
    }

    draw();

    setTimeout(frame, 1);
}
```

Given a starting and ending position and velocity, the formula for the acceleration required (assuming constant acceleration) is:

[image: (2 * v0 * (vf - v0) + (vf - v0)^2) / (2 * (xf - x0))]

So initializing the object like this:

```
var obj = {
    start: 10,
    height: 200,
    stopDist: 300, 
    dest: 500,
    lastTime: new Date().getTime(),
    velocity: 0.05,
    destVelocity: 0.01,
    pos: undefined,
    acceleration: undefined
};
```

here is how we can kick this all off:

```
function start(){
    var v0 = obj.velocity,
        vf = obj.destVelocity,
        x0 = obj.start,
        xf = x0 + x.stopDist,
        vDelta = vf - v0;

    obj.pos = x0;
    obj.acceleration = (2 * v0 * vDelta + vDelta * vDelta) / (2 * (xf - x0));

    frame();
}
```

As I've done above, it's helpful to solve the 1d case first. Here is that, all put together.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawDot(color, x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawDot("red", obj.pos, obj.height);
    drawDot("white", obj.start, obj.height);
    drawDot("green", obj.dest, obj.height);
    drawDot("yellow", obj.start + obj.stopDist, obj.height);

    ctx.fillText("x = " + obj.pos.toFixed(5), 20, 400);
    ctx.fillText("v = " + obj.velocity.toFixed(5), 20, 420);
    ctx.fillText("distance traveled: " + (obj.pos - obj.start).toFixed(2), 20, 440);
}

var obj = {
    start: 10,
    height: 200,
    stopDist: 300,
    dest: 500,
    lastTime: new Date().getTime(),
    velocity: 0.05,
    destVelocity: 0.01,
    pos: undefined,
    acceleration: undefined
};

function frame() {
    var t = new Date().getTime(),
        tDelta = t - obj.lastTime;
    obj.lastTime = t;

    obj.pos += obj.velocity * tDelta;
    if (obj.velocity > obj.destVelocity) {
        obj.velocity += obj.acceleration * tDelta;
    }

    draw();

    setTimeout(frame, 1);
}

function start() {
    var v0 = obj.velocity,
        vf = obj.destVelocity,
        x0 = obj.start,
        xf = x0 + obj.stopDist,
        vDelta = vf - v0;

    obj.pos = x0;
    obj.acceleration = (2 * v0 * vDelta + vDelta * vDelta) / (2 * (xf - x0));

    frame();
}

start();
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7842xcb/3/

---

And here is the 2d version (brace yourself):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawDot(color, x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x - 2, y - 2, 4, 4);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawDot("red", obj.pos.x, obj.pos.y);
    drawDot("white", obj.start.x, obj.start.y);
    drawDot("green", obj.dest.x, obj.dest.y);
    drawDot("yellow", obj.stopLocation.x, obj.stopLocation.y);
    
    var dx = obj.pos.x - obj.start.x,
        dy = obj.pos.y - obj.start.y,
        dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy *dy),
        v = obj.velocity,
        speed = Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);
    
    ctx.fillText("distance traveled: " + dist.toFixed(5), 20, 400);
    ctx.fillText("speed:             " + speed.toFixed(5), 20, 420);
}

var obj = {
    start: { x: 400, y: 230 },
    stopDist: 350,
    dest: { x: 50, y: 330 },
    lastTime: new Date().getTime(),
    startSpeed: 0.05,
    destSpeed: 0.1,

    pos: null,
    velocity: null,
    destVelocity: null,
    acceleration: null
};

function sign(value) {
    return value > 0 ? 1 : (value < 0 ? -1 : 0);
}

function reached(start, current, dest) {
    return current === dest || 
        sign(current - dest) === sign(dest - start);
}

function frame() {
    var t = new Date().getTime(),
        tDelta = t - obj.lastTime,
        v = obj.velocity,
        destv = obj.destVelocity,
        startv = obj.startVelocity;
    obj.lastTime = t;

    obj.pos.x += v.x * tDelta;
    obj.pos.y += v.y * tDelta;
    
    if (!reached(startv.x, v.x, destv.x) ||
        !reached(startv.y, v.y, destv.y)) {
        v.x += obj.acceleration.x * tDelta;
        v.y += obj.acceleration.y * tDelta;
    }

    draw();

    setTimeout(frame, 1);
}

function calcAcceleration(p0, pf, v0, vf) {
    var vDelta = vf - v0;
    
    return pf ===  p0 
        ? 0
        : (2 * v0 * vDelta + vDelta * vDelta) / (2 * (pf - p0));
}

function start() {
    // positions and deltas
    var start = obj.start,
        dest = obj.dest,
        dx = dest.x - start.x,
        dy = dest.y - start.y,
        totalDistance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    
    // x and y component ratio
    var cx = dx / totalDistance,
        cy = dy / totalDistance;
    
    var stopLocation = { x: cx * obj.stopDist + start.x, 
                         y: cy * obj.stopDist + start.y };
    
    // velocities
    var startSpeed = obj.startSpeed,
        destSpeed = obj.destSpeed,
        startVelocity = { x: cx * startSpeed, y: cy * startSpeed },
        endVelocity = { x: cx * destSpeed, y: cy * destSpeed };
    console.log(startVelocity);
    console.log(endVelocity);
    
    // acceleration
    var acceleration = { 
        x: calcAcceleration(start.x, stopLocation.x, startVelocity.x, endVelocity.x),
        y: calcAcceleration(start.y, stopLocation.y, startVelocity.y, endVelocity.y) 
    };

    obj.pos = Object.create(start);
    obj.startVelocity = startVelocity;
    obj.velocity = Object.create(startVelocity);
    obj.stopLocation = stopLocation;
    obj.destVelocity = endVelocity;
    obj.acceleration = acceleration;
    
    frame();
}

start();
```

```css
#canvas{
    background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="700"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1r3q4oob/3/

**Edit** Regarding the fix I made after the fact:

The problem with my original implementation was that it would only update the velocity if both the X and Y components of the current velocity were greater than the target velocity. This would prevent the correct behavior if:

- The X or Y component of both the start and end velocity were 0 (i.e. if it were travelling perfectly horizontally or vertically)
- The X or Y component of the start and end velocity were negative (i.e. if it were travelling up and to the left)
- The velocity needed to increase rather than decrease (i.e. the dot were *speeding up* to a target velocity)

I resolved this with the addition of the `reached()` function, which basically returns true if (a) the destination velocity is *between* the current velocity and the start velocity (i.e. the current velocity has gone past the destination velocity), or (b) the current velocity is equal to the destination velocity.

Comment: I got it working on jsFiddle, but when I implement it into my website for some reason, the check to see if `velocity.x > destVelocity.x` equals `false`. But for `y axis`, it is `true`. Which means it won't alter the velocity with the acceleration. Don't know why this is the case, the target speed is set lower than the start speed. =/ Can i show you the code in a paste file for you to see where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Ok i did some digging, there is an issue if the path is for example   on a straight axis where by destination and start x or y is the same. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8kzptxus/ notice no change in velocity

Comment: Also tried it on your example code unmodified: http://jsfiddle.net/au5ht6oh/ with no change in velocity

Comment: @Dave Ok, looks like there was the same issue when travelling in any direction other than down and to the right. I've fixed that and it should also allow going from a lower starting speed to a higher destination speed.

Comment: @Dave If you click on the "edited ___ hours ago" link, you can see which parts of my code I changed. I've also added a short explanation to the end of my answer.

Comment: thanks for the help, it works - just a quick question about your reached function. I tried to check if the sprite reaches its target speed, even if i set the target speed to zero. It never truely reaches the value. Observe the overlay text as it travels to see what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6uob2uaq/. My question - is this a limitation of computers?

Comment: @Dave Yes, it is essentially because there are repeated imperfect addition operations with rounding errors and the result of the repeated calculations doesn't perfectly reach the destination value. You can get around this by doing an `else { obj.velocity = obj.destVelocity; }` to "lock the value in" once the destination value is reached: http://jsfiddle.net/6uob2uaq/2/ Computers are capable of carrying out the calculation accurately, but the IEEE floating point arithmetic that JavaScript and most languages use isn't up to the task.

Comment: thanks for the info i did a check against epsilon to solve the floating point issue - works a treat! Thanks!